# Understanding JS functions syntax (applies to other languages as well, I'm sure)

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Here's a bit of code. The comments are as I understand things right now.

```
//Whenever the cursor moves on the document, 
//execute function(e), e = undefined at the moment. And what is it doing there anyway? :P
document.onmousemove = function(e) {

//The variable event gets the value of e 
//(undefined is falsy, so not that) OR that of window.event, 
//which is true and contains lots of info on cursor position and other stuff.
var event = e || window.event;

//Record the value of the clientX key from the window.event array to variable  
//window.mouseX (why window.? with just mouseX, nothing gets recorded)
window.mouseX = event.clientX;

//Same as above for vertical position
window.mouseY = event.clientY; 
}
```

The code assigns mouse x/y positions to window.mouseX and mouseY respectively.

The answers I'm looking for are:

1) Why pass an undefined variable into the function just to have it compared with something known to be true (at least in all cases where it would matter, why would it matter if window.event would be false, because then our function would not be called as it's bound to document.onmousemove?)

2) Why does it matter that the X/Y mouse pos. gets recorded in window.mouseX rather than just mouseX or alligator or peanut?

Please guide me through this with your (comments on the code) || otherwis(e). Thank you.

Comment: 1) `e = undefined at the moment. And what is it doing there anyway?` - `e` is a function argument ... 2) no, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why pass an undefined variable into the function just to have it compared with something known to be true (at least in all cases where it would matter, why would it matter if window.event would be false, because then our function would not be called as it's bound to document.onmousemove?)

`e` *should* always be defined when the event handler is called by the browser in response to an event firing.

The test to see if it isn't defined and to fallback to a global event object is for backwards compatibility with truly ancient browsers from before the days when this was standardised.

> Why does it matter that the X/Y mouse pos. gets recorded in window.mouseX rather than just mouseX or alligator or peanut?

Writing the code that way makes it very clear to people reading it that a global is being set. There is no room for ambiguity so people maintaining the code don't have to spent time looking to see where the variable is declared.

Comment: Oh yeah - I was trying to read the value of e before the event fired and got undefined. Still, I don't understand how e gets the value for event, as you can write down banana and just refer that later in the code, everything still works. Does the function parameter of the function following an event automatically get assigned the value of whatever the event is communicating? How about if I write x = 7; x = function(z); will z get the value-key pair x = 7?

Comment: When a function is called, arguments can be passed to it. This is true when the function is called by code you've written. This is true when the function is called by code written by someone else (such as the built in event handling code in browsers). The name of the argument doesn't matter. If you call it `e` then the first value passed will be assigned to a variable called `e`. If you call it `z` then the first value passed will be assigned to a variable called `z`. If you call it `spooky_twilight` then etc etc.

Comment: If you write `x = 7; x = function(z);` then you'll get a syntax error. If you write `x = 7; x = foo(123);` then `x` will be assigned `7` and then it will get the return value of `foo(123)` (which will replace `7`).

Comment: Ahh so in my original example, the event will trigger a function, into which event variables are carried and something is done with them. So in all simplicity, The event runs a program that does something. Did I get it right? It seems I'm having a had time wrapping my head around =, which in this case is used in a more complex manner than just say x = 7. There's a larger set of data here being carried into what is something that's actually functional, not just a set value. So yeah, it's assigning like x = 7, but it's effects are more dynamic.